# Setting a field of a class's instance with reflection

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests

I have the following issue related to reflection , I have a method which looks like this :

```
  [TestMethod()]
 public void steamAccess()
        {
            testRead = new TestRead();
            SteamMap a = new SteamMap();

           // Preparing the parameters of the CSV actions
            a.writeMessageParams.UIItemEditText = TestContext.DataRow["SearchQuery"].ToString();

           //Read and Execute the TestMethod
            testRead.Read(a, TestContext);
        }
```

This is a `CodedUITest`, SteamMap is a class (`uiTest map`).
`WriteMessageParams` is a class, actually the real method is `WriteMessage` but this class allows me to override the string that gets used into my tests by the `WriteMessage` method, and I plan to make this part of the code more dynamically in  the `Read` method. :

```
   a.writeMessageParams.UIItemEditText = TestContext.DataRow["SearchQuery"].ToString();
```

My problem happens in testRead.Read context as follows :

When this method is running I have access to all actions from the respective instance ( `a` in my case ) and if they are supposed to have to use a `a.writeMessageParams.UIItemEditText` context I know it, how I get the info isn't the problem, the problem is how to make the previously mentioned code to run dynamically as I have tried :

```
/* I've done this because I know that each method that is supposed to end up with Params, for example a method called WriteMessage, it's class is called WriteMessageParams*/

public void Read(object obj, TestContext testContext)
{
//simplified code
//trying to access/get to the current instance's WriteMessageParam class 
Object testObj = obj.GetType().GetMember(subMethod.Code + "Param");

//null
MessageBox.Show(testObj.GetType().ToString());

// trying to access the UIItemEditText field ( which is declared as public) and modify it accordingly 
FieldInfo subMethodField = testObj.GetType().GetField("UIItemEditText");
subMethodField.SetValue(testObj,testContext.DataRow[subMethod.CsvColumn].ToString());
}
```

I've had a read over this article and tried few things
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6z33zd7h%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

My problem is that I have the object of an instance and I try to access this object's class and modify that class's field .

I'd appreciate any help,
Thanks

Edit 1:
This is how the class I'm trying to access looks like :

```
public partial class SteamMap
    { //simplified to what classes/methods interest me

            public virtual writeMessageParams writeMessageParams
        {
            get
            {
                if ((this.mwriteMessageParams == null))
                {
                    this.mwriteMessageParams = new writeMessageParams();
                }
                return this.mwriteMessageParams;
            }
        }

public class writeMessageParams
    {

        #region Fields
        /// <summary>
        /// Type 'test' in text box
        /// </summary>
        public string UIItemEditText = "test";
        #endregion
    }
    }
```

Edit 2 - I've tried by using GetNestedType, still no success....

```
Object testObj = obj.GetType().GetNestedType("writeMessageParams",BindingFlags.Public);
 MessageBox.Show(testObj.GetType().ToString());
```

[image]

Comment: What exactly are  you trying to do? Setting a field of an object?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do

Comment: The issue is that the class where I try to set it's field is nested within the SteamMap class declared above. I've got no idea how to reach it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you, you have a class like

```
public partial class SteamMap
{  

    private writeMessageParams mwriteMessageParams ;

    public virtual writeMessageParams  writeMessageParams1
    {
        get
        {
            if ((this.mwriteMessageParams == null))
            {
                this.mwriteMessageParams = new writeMessageParams();
            }
            return this.mwriteMessageParams;
        }
    }

    public class writeMessageParams
    {            
        public string UIItemEditText = "test";       
    }
}
```

(your code doesn't compile because you have writeMessageParams both as the class and the property, so I have changed the property to writeMessageParams1)

And you want to change UIItemEditText, which you can do like

```
public void UpdateUI(object obj, string newValue)
{
    var property = obj.GetType().GetProperty("writeMessageParams1");

    var writeMessageParams1 = property.GetValue(obj);


    var uiFld = wp.GetType().GetField("UIItemEditText");

    uiFld.SetValue(writeMessageParams1, newValue);

}
```

which can be called like

```
SteamMap sm = new SteamMap();
Write(sm, "Hello");
```

The key is to use `.GetProperty` for the property and `.GetField` for the field.

Comment: You have saved me from one more day of reading the msdn documentation for this issue. Apparently it works by searching directly for my desired method, now my CSV value read works dynamically . Thanks a lot.